# setAttribute is not working

Tags: javascript, asp.net

This code nested in an ascx control. the onclientclick event works and there are no error but the label text is not changed? What am I missing?

```
                <asp:Button 
                ID="btnUpload" runat="server" CssClass="Uploadbtn1"    OnClientClick="BePatient()" OnClick="btnUpload_Click" 
                Text="Upload" Width="62px"  align="center"/>
             <Label ID="Label1" ></Label>

            <br />
            <br />

            <asp:Label ID="ErrorMessageLbl" runat="server"></asp:Label>




            <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
            function BePatient() {

                    var lbl = document.getElementById('<%=ErrorMessageLbl.ClientID%>');
                    var lblText = lbl.getAttribute("innerText");
                    // var lblText = lbl.getAttribute("Text");                    // this did not work
                    //var lblText = lbl.getAttribute("innerHtml");               // this did not work
                    lbl.setAttribute(lblText, "Please be patient this will take awhile!");
                  }
            </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

The way you [set an element's text](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent) is like this:

```
var lbl = document.getElementById('<%=ErrorMessageLbl.ClientID%>');
lbl.innerText = "Please be patient this will take awhile!";
```

If for some reason you actually wanted to set an attribute named 'innerText', then you'd use

```
var lbl = document.getElementById('<%=ErrorMessageLbl.ClientID%>');
lbl.setAttribute('innerText', 'Please be patient this will take awhile!');
```